# Каскадное удаление в postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет!

Возник вопрос с каскадным удалением записей из таблиц в postgre.
Задача банальна: при удалении записи из одной таблицы необходимо также удалять записи из других таблиц, ссылающихся на удаляемую.
Имеется таблица директорий и таблица файлов. В директориях имеется поле parent_directory_id, значение в котором означает, что одна папка вложена в другую. 
В таблице files имеется поле directory_id, которое хранит ссылку на папку, в которую вложен файл. Необходимо при удалении записи из directories удалять все, что "внутри", т.е. все, что ссылается на эту запись прямо и косвенно.

В данный момент при попытке удаления строки из directories вылетает ошибка нарушения целостности("UPDATE или DELETE в таблице "directories" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "files_directory_id_fkey" таблицы "files"). Без файлов папки удаляются правильно.

Скрипт создания структуры:

```
create table directories (
directory_id serial primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
parent_directory_id int,
is_final bool default true
);

create table files (
id_file serial primary key,
directory_id int references directories(directory_id),
name varchar(50) not null,
size double not null,
modify_date timestamp not null default now()
);

alter table directories add constraint cascade_del
foreign key (parent_directory_id) references directories(directory_id) match simple
on update no action on delete cascade;
```

последовательность операций:

```
insert into directories(name) values ('f');
insert into directories(name, parent_directory_id) values ('k', 3);
insert into files(directory_id, name, size) values(4, 'test', 2.1);
```

при попытке удаления вылетает ошибка

```
delete from directories where directory_id = 3;
UPDATE или DELETE в таблице "directories" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "files_directory_id_fkey" таблицы "files"
```

Comment: Кстати, пока помню: заведите себе привычку именовать колонки единообразно. А то `directories`/`directory_id` и `files`/`id_file` не есть хорошо.

Comment: да, уже. спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Необходимо при удалении записи из directories удалять все, что "внутри", т.е. все, что ссылается на эту запись прямо и косвенно.

Именно! А вы предписали стирать только папки. Но папки удалить нельзя, пока на них ссылаются файлы, согласно:

```
directory_id int references directories(directory_id),
```

Там прячется `ON DELETE NO ACTION`, [см. документацию](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/ddl-constraints.html#ddl-constraints-fk):

> `NO ACTION` означает, что если зависимые строки продолжают существовать при проверке ограничения, возникает ошибка (это поведение по умолчанию).

Comment: Ну хорошо, я добавляю: 
alter table files add constraint del_files
foreign key (directory_id) references directories(directory_id)
 on update no action on delete cascade;
Тем самым я говорю, что при попытке удаления directory_id удалять все файлы, что на него ссылаются. Но все равно выдает ошибку
В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что мне либо надо set null(что по логике неверно и надо бы добавить constraint на это), либо делать fk в другом направлении: что бы directory_id в directories ссылался на files

Comment: @GlebTuchinnscky *Но все равно выдает ошибку* - какую?

Comment: "UPDATE или DELETE в таблице "directories" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "files_directory_id_fkey" таблицы "files"
ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  На ключ (directory_id)=(4) всё ещё есть ссылки в таблице "

Comment: Ну, ключ без `on delete`, судя по всему, по-прежнему существует. По названию констрейнта смотрите, оно выводится в сообщении.

Comment: Заработало. Все решилось после удаления сначала стандартного ограничения, которое создавалось еще при создании таблицы, имя которому дал postgres(в строке directory_id int references directories(directory_id)). А затем добавления нового, которое описывал выше через alter table. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Ты сам ответил на свой вопрос - "Без файлов папки удаляются правильно."

```
directory_id int references directories(directory_id)
```

constraint на эту связь не полный, не указал on update и on delete